# Android how to send data to a broadcast receiver using intents

Tags: android, notifications, broadcastreceiver, proximity

I'm writing an app in which I launch a proximity alert every time I'm near a specific point of interest(I read the poi from a mysql db). 
When the BroadcastReceiver gets the intent, it creates a notification and everything works fine. When I click on the notification I would like an activity to start, so to do this I need to send some parameters (basically strings) to the broadcast receiver, so that it could pass this parameters to the activity I want to start. 
The problem is that when I try to pass these parameters through the intent to the broadcast receiver I get this error: error receiving broadcast intent flg=0x10 has extras.

I sent the parameters in this way:

```
 private void addProximityAlert(Annuncio a){
   double latitudine = a.lat; 
   double longitudine = a.lon; 
   Intent intent = new Intent(PROX_ALERT_INTENT);
   intent.putExtra("nome", nome); 
   PendingIntent pi = PendingIntent.getBroadcast(this, 0, intent,0);
   locationManager.addProximityAlert(latitudine, longitudine, RAGGIO, ALERT_EXPIRATION, pi); 
   IntentFilter filter = new IntentFilter(PROX_ALERT_INTENT); 
   registerReceiver(new ProximityIntentReceiver(),filter);
}
```

this is the receiver:

```
public class ProximityIntentReceiver extends BroadcastReceiver{  
   public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent){
       String nome = intent.getExtras().getString("nome");
       Log.v("nome", nome);


   } 
}
```

What am I missing?

```
06-29 22:42:46.103: E/AndroidRuntime(3723): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
06-29 22:42:46.103: E/AndroidRuntime(3723): java.lang.RuntimeException: Error receiving broadcast Intent { act=com.carmen.progettosmp.PROXIMITY_ALERT flg=0x10 (has extras) } in com.carmen.progettosmp.ProximityIntentReceiver@427a2f58
06-29 22:42:46.103: E/AndroidRuntime(3723):     at android.app.LoadedApk$ReceiverDispatcher$Args.run(LoadedApk.java:795)
06-29 22:42:46.103: E/AndroidRuntime(3723):     at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:615)
06-29 22:42:46.103: E/AndroidRuntime(3723):     at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:92)
06-29 22:42:46.103: E/AndroidRuntime(3723):     at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:153)
06-29 22:42:46.103: E/AndroidRuntime(3723):     at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4987)
06-29 22:42:46.103: E/AndroidRuntime(3723):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
06-29 22:42:46.103: E/AndroidRuntime(3723):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
06-29 22:42:46.103: E/AndroidRuntime(3723):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:821)
06-29 22:42:46.103: E/AndroidRuntime(3723):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:584)
06-29 22:42:46.103: E/AndroidRuntime(3723):     at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
06-29 22:42:46.103: E/AndroidRuntime(3723): Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException: println needs a message
06-29 22:42:46.103: E/AndroidRuntime(3723):     at android.util.Log.println_native(Native Method)
06-29 22:42:46.103: E/AndroidRuntime(3723):     at android.util.Log.v(Log.java:117)
06-29 22:42:46.103: E/AndroidRuntime(3723):     at com.carmen.progettosmp.ProximityIntentReceiver.onReceive(ProximityIntentReceiver.java:29)
06-29 22:42:46.103: E/AndroidRuntime(3723):     at android.app.LoadedApk$ReceiverDispatcher$Args.run(LoadedApk.java:785)
06-29 22:42:46.103: E/AndroidRuntime(3723):     ... 9 more
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you are creating a notification, you have to create a PendingIntent which in turn holds an Intent. Can't you set those extras in that Intent?. Also, it sounds you might benefit from the Geofencing API. One more thing, you are looking for the string "ciao" as a key, shouldn't you look for the key nome?

Comment: Actually I'm putting those extras in the intent but it doesn't work. Maybe I'm doing it in the wrong way. Could you please have a look at my code and help me to find what's wrong?

Comment: Did you see my edit? You are looking for the "ciao" key. Did you add that key to the Intent?

Comment: Yes, sorry. I am looking for the key nome, I just was wrong when I wrote the post, but in my code I am actually looking for the string nome but it doesn't work

Comment: Have you set the fine and coarse permissions in the manifest?

Comment: Yes, I have set the following permissions: android.permission.INTERNET, permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE,android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE,com.google.android.providers.gsf.permission.READ_GSERVICES,android.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION,android.permission.ACCESS_MOCK_LOCATION,android.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION,android.permission.VIBRATE

Comment: What is the value of PROX_ALERT_INTENT?

Comment: private static final String PROX_ALERT_INTENT = "com.carmen.progettosmp.PROXIMITY_ALERT";

Comment: Can you post the stack trace?